# Convolution theorem for images and kernels

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, image-processing

I'd like to understand the convolution theorem for Fourier transforms applied to images and kernels.

The theorem states that $F(f *g) = F(f) \cdot F(g)$, where F is the Fourier transform operator, * denotes the convolution operator and $\cdot$ elementwise multiplication. I struggle to interpret this relationship for images where I apply a convolution in form of a filter matrix, for instance like the Sobel operator.

I think in this case, f is my image and g is the filter matrix. However, I don't see, why $F(f)$ and $F(g)$ should have the same dimensionality and if they don't I cannot apply elementwise multiplication. I wondered whether I should pad the kernel with zero elements until it has the same dimensionality as the image but I'm not sure whether this is the correct way.

Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: What do you mean by dimensionality?

Comment: By dimensionality I mean the size of the image, I consider an image a element $\mathbb{R}^{h \times w}$ with h,w the height and width of the image.

Comment: what are you talking about? the fourier transform is a complex function!

Comment: The DFT is different from the FT.  And in the discrete case, cyclic convolution (the result of using DFTs and IDFT to perform convolution), is generally different from linear convolution, unless you are careful about zero padding and discarding the tail ends of results.

Comment: Section 9.9 of this text book, esp. equation 9.9.10, discusses linear convolution vs. cyclic convolution and the conditions under which they are equivalent (for the 1 dimensional case): https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/orfanidis-i2sp.pdf

Comment: This changes nothing. The multiplication is taking place for objects in their respective structure with no dimensionality issues